# Launch Helper Application with Launch Arguments in the Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox

I'm trying to launch a helper application that is located inside my main apps's bundle directory with a launch argument while sandboxing is turned on. The helper application is launched via `/usr/bin/open` through `NSTask` or `posix_spawn`. While the helper is launched, it never receives any launch arguments I've sent with it. This must have something to do with the apps both being sandboxed. What's the official way to do this?